# Why does the iOS Health app sometimes drop my step count by hundreds of steps?

Tags: health.app

I use an activity tracker 3rd party app that syncs with Apple's Health app, and I have a daily goal of 10,000 steps. Sometimes (not frequently, but once in a while), the step count in the Health app drops by at least a few hundred steps, e.g., it was around 9,400, and then dropped to 8,674 steps. This happens seemingly at random. Any idea about this?

Comment: I noticed something similar when using a Fitbit, but when I switched to an Apple Watch all my steps were counted. I wonder if maybe the third-party app while counting all the steps only reports to Apple Health for a certain time period, i.e. 8a-10p?

Comment: As I understand it, the 3rd party app just receives data from the Apple Health app, i.e. the Health app is the "source of truth" about the steps. (but please correct me if I'm wrong) So it seems Health was the one that "corrected" its count, but I don't know why?

Comment: If a non-Apple fitness tracker is being used, the associated third-party app will **send** data to Apple Health. The third-party app is the source.

Comment: No, the 3rd party app is getting data from the Health app. It doesn't have its own data to provide the Health app.